# SystemVerilog $bits() return type?

Tags: system-verilog

As I know from SystemVerilog 3.1a Language Reference Manual "The $bits system function returns the number of bits required to hold an expression as a bit stream."

1. What type this function returns?
2. Is this type machine dependent maximum size?
3. Is this maximum systemverilog type longint?

Any link to spec or docs revealing this mystery would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you care about the its type? do you have an use case where this is important?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, Bob! E.g. I can probably try to use $bits(vec) where vec has width more than $bits() can count. But probably i wont be able to create such wide  vector.

Comment: I may want to save $bits() return value in some parameter. And in such case i must be caution if my parameter type is able to fit the whole value from $bits(). This one is more realistic use case.

Comment: The SystemVerilog 3.1a LRM is 17 years old. The current [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) is publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the System Verilog standard:

> *20.6.2 Expression size system function*
> The $bits system function returns the number of bits required to hold an expression as a bit stream. The
> return type is **integer**

> *6.11 Integer data types*
> **integer** -- 4-state data type, 32-bit signed integer

Comment: Thank you, Serge! That is correct. My SystemVerilog 3.1a Language Reference Manual is obsolete and has not got such information.

Comment: @Oleg you should stop using pre-historic documents :-). Try to find the latest standard which is IEEE1800-2017

Answer (score 1):

In terms of number of bits you can test in your simulator with a code like this

```sv
`define inspect(arg) \
  $display(`"arg = %b = %d (%0d bits)`", arg, arg, $bits(arg));

module bit_width;
  reg [4:0] x;
  reg [4'd4:4'd0] y;
  initial begin
    `inspect($bits(x));
    `inspect($bits(y));
  end
endmodule
```

In Icarus Verilog it prints

```
$bits(x) = 00000000000000000000000000000101 =          5 (32 bits)
$bits(y) = 00000000000000000000000000000101 =          5 (32 bits)
```

Suggesting that both will give 32 bits, fixed size.

To be honest, after reading your question, before testing, I would expect `$bits(y)` to have 4-bits.